# iFrame not showing video

Tags: html, iframe

I wanted to embed YouTube video and copied embeding code from YouTube. Here it is: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sru9ydoxe88?si=cbzk_yu6ybklsogf" title="youtube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I tried embedding another video, but it didn't work either. I tried opening it in Ark, Little Ark and Safari and it didn't work in all of them.

Answer (score -1):

If your YouTube video isn't displaying with the provided code, you can try the following simplified version:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sru9ydoxe88" title="YouTube Video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Ensure you remove any additional parameters, like `?si=cbzk_yu6ybklsogf`, from the URL. If the issue persists, consider the factors mentioned earlier, such as checking the browser compatibility, website rules, and looking for JavaScript errors.